# Boole on language

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

I am trying to understand the meaning of this quote of Boole 1847:

"Language is an instrument of Logic, but not an indispensable instrument."

There are something logical outside language?

They are not the same λόγος ?

Comment: Where is the quote taken from?

Comment: See George Boole: The Mathematical Analysis of Logic. 1847, p.81 https://books.google.de/books?id=d6Gkkvui96QC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=Language+is+an+instrument+of+Logic,+but+not+an+indispensable+instrument&source=bl&ots=IXDUa6rNAT&sig=r5-IoGJLhI_RuFDL3Puu53Ci9YU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAmoVChMIoNPviPqSxwIVg4ksCh17LwpE#v=onepage&q=Language%20is%20an%20instrument%20of%20Logic%2C%20but%20not%20an%20indispensable%20instrument&f=false

Answer (score 2):

The entire paragraph from the postscript on page 81 of Boole's "The Mathematical Analysis of Logic", from where your quote was extracted, reads as follows:

> The remarks on the connexion between Logic and Language, p. 5, are scarcely sufficiently explicit. Both the one and the other I hold to depend very materially upon our ability to form general notions by the faculty of abstraction. Language is an instrument of Logic, but not an indispensable instrument.

What we find on pages 4-5 is the following:

> That which renders Logic possible, is the existence in our minds of general notions,-our ability to conceive of a class, and to designate its individual members by a common name. The theory of Logic is thus intimately connected with that of Language. A successful attempt to express logical propositions by symbols, the laws of whose combinations should be founded upon the laws of the mental processes which they represent, would, so far, be a step toward a philosophical language. But this is a view which we need not here follow into detail.*

The footnote on that page begins this way (emphasis added):

> *This view is well expressed in one of Blanco White's Letters:-"Logic is for the most part a collection of technical rules founded on classification. The Syllogism is nothing but a result of the classification of things, which the mind **naturally** and **necessarily** forms, in forming a language(...)"

It seems to me that Boole expresses here a view that was common in his time, of Language as a natural phenomenon, and of Logic as the somewhat idealized structure of (adequate) reasoning. Language may have a theory of its own, based on observation, and because the mind spontaneously reproduces abstract forms in Language (which is why Logic as a human endeavor is possible, to begin with), Language can be instrumental to (a theory of) Logic, insofar this theory is produced by Language-speaking humans. Such a theory of Logic, existing nonetheless independently of Language, could in principle be realized by a different kind of mental process, one that is general enough for abstract reasoning, but not necessarily embedded in Language.

He could be hinting at the possibility of "logical machines", that would be entirely within the scope of the speculations of that time. I don't know enough to explain how far has he gone explicitly in that direction, but we all know how instrumental his work has been to the development of the thinking machines we have today.